# Any online tool to get the value of XML nodes?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Any online tool to get the value of XML nodes?
also to parse the xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know why you need this, but here is a XPath-Tester:
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Enter your XML and your XPath to the note, and it will be highlighted.

Comment: Changed the tool